# Download multiple packages in parallel from a single repository with apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I'm painfully watching my `apt dist-upgrade` command download each package in a very long list, and what makes it painful is that packages are downloaded one-by-one. I fail to see why this process couldn't be sped up by downloading multiple packages simultaneously!

For example, if apt is downloading Chrome (PPA), Syncthing (PPA), and Ubuntu system updates (non-PPA), three simultaneous downloads will begin, one for Chrome, one for Syncthing, and one for the Ubuntu system updates.

Since all update packages are downloaded before any installation even begins, I don't see any reason why multiple packages for Ubuntu system updates coming from a single repository can't be downloaded in parallel.

I would really like to know if anyone knows a way to make this happen? Can I downloaded multiple package upgrade files in parallel from a single repository when running `apt dist-upgrade` or `apt upgrade`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon digging around some more, I found [apt-fast](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast). There is an Ubuntu PPA that can be used for installation. The `apt-fast` command is able not only to download packages in parallel but also to download using multiple connections per package and from multiple mirrors. Documentation is all available on the GitHub page linked above.